# How to send subscriptions to a non-primary address

Tags: civimember, addresses

We would like to manage the sending of our magazine via CiviMember as [« The Monthly » made it](https://civicrm.org/blog/johnd/civicrm-manage-magazine-subscriptions).

We have an additional problem: certain contacts wish to receive their subscription to an address different from the primary address, the primary address remaining the address for the others sendings.

Is there a (simple ?) way to associate a particular address with a membership ?

Comment: Take a look at this post, it has info on setting bulk email addresses. Not sure if it is what you are looking for but explains how to use various emails for bulk mailings. http://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/341/how-do-i-send-to-multiple-email-addresses-for-a-contact-in-civimail/342#342

Comment: Thanks for the link, but I forgot to specify that I was spoking about snail mails. And we have to send only the number of magazines that the contacts subscribe.

Comment: Do you use the same Location Type for the address that the magazine is sent to eg Postal Address? And are you using Drupal or another CMS?

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new Location Type at Administer > Customize Data and Screens > Dropdown Options > Location Types. I take it that most contacts will use the Primary Snailmail address, but that a small proportion won't. So I would manually create and manage the use of the override location type for the smaller group.

There are various ways to handle the creation of the mailing labels. You could either export both primary and override addresses to Excel and then do a bit of coding in Excel to choose the override if it exists else the primary. Or you could do a bit of custom coding to provide tokens in CiviCRM that do the same thing. You could probably also do it in Smarty fairly easily if you have full mailing address for both locations in two variables exposed to Smarty.

Unfortunately I can't think of an easy way to print the labels in core CiviCRM. Maybe others will. Good luck.